# Trouble getting suggestions in vs code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am learning c++ code and using vs code as IDE. It was going good but now I am not getting suggestion when I write my code. I am using C/C++ extension by intellisense. I tried reinstalling it, resetting its settings but nothing worked. Please help.

[This is the only suggestion it shows when I type #include.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW3Et.jpg)

Comment: I'm guessing. Intellisense often works out what to offer on the basis of the extension of the file name. So maybe save the file with, for example, the .cpp extension and then see if VS gives you a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save(cmd+s / ctrl+s) the file in order for intellisense to work.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the file name is Untitled-1. Intellisense will not work as you need to notify VS Code that it is a C/C++ file.

You should create a new file and save it with the .c or .cpp extension.

In case you want to add autocomplete for external libraries like QT5 or OpenCV, you need to configure intellisense by following [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_cc-configurations). Add the include path of your external library to the includePath in c_cpp_properties.json.

Example -

```json
    "includePath": [
          "${myDefaultIncludePath}", // Adds intellisense for the files from current workspace folder. 
          "path/to/include/folder"
     ]
```

[Reference for c_cpp_properties.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

Comment: When you create a new file it let's you "Select a language" -- but it does not turn on intellisense. This is where the confusion comes from.